# You have enabled the CloudMessaging service in Developer Console, but it appears as though your Podfile is missing

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get this error message:

> You have enabled the CloudMessaging service in Developer Console, but it appears as though your Podfile is missing the line: 'pod "Google/CloudMessaging" or you may need to run `pod update` in your project directory.

But I have this pod files already

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

As GCM is deprecated, and now FCM is what we are using.

Comment: Hi niravdesai21. Since you are an experienced user, may I ask you to put more effort into posting your questions please? My broad advice is: (1) quote blocks for errors, (2) code formatting for something that needs to be pre-formatted, (3) use a spell-checker, (4) refrain from adding chatty material. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer I will be careful here on.

Answer (score 0):

First try pod install and in case it does not work then run this -

sudo pod update